# How to add instrumented test and unit test source sets to existing Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I create a new Gradle project, I get two additional directories in addition to the main app directory, one for unit testing, and one for instrumented testing e.g.

```
java
  com.example.myapplication
  com.example.myapplication (androidTest) <--- instrumented testing
  com.example.myapplication (test) <---- unit testing
```

I guess these two directories basically contain the source sets which Android Studio will use Gradle to build and launch the tests with to a device.

However, I am working with a project which is lacking these two directories. I only have the app source directory.

All tutorials only show how to create tests assuming the two testing directories have been auto generated by Android Studio.

I need to know how to create these source set directories, but its all just magic to me, and I have no idea how to do it.

I guess in the worst case scenario, I can just create a new project, and port my code to it, but I hate doing that, because it's not really a solution, just a lame work-around.

I'm using the Android Gradle plugin, so I think I'm close, but no tomato. Any advice?

Thanks.

Comment: They are just directories. Right-click over `src/` in Android Studio and choose New > Directory from the context menu. You will also need to copy over some things from the `build.gradle` file related to testing -- search the `build.gradle` of a test-enabled project for `test` to see what you will need.

Answer (score 2):

CommonsWare is correct. You just have to create the directory `androidTest` and change the configuration in the `build.gradle`  (roughly speaking).

1. Go to to `Project` view
2. Right click on on `src`
3. Select `View in Terminal` context option
4. Do `ls` in `src` directory
5. Do `mkdir androidTest` and `mkdir main` and move `com` to `main`

the go to `build.gradle` and replace `src`

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // ...
 }
```

with `src/main` (and possibly set the root on `androidTest` as well I guess)

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')

    // ...
}
```

then entire source set block will look like this for me at least

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    androidTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
    }
    androidTest.setRoot('src/androidTest')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
```

the finally remember to add default runner if not included already so this

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.slacorp.myApp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 190
    versionName "23.5"
}
```

becomes this

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.slacorp.myApp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 190
    versionName "23.5"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

then add dependencies so this

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':lib-android-common-ui')
    implementation project(':android-lite')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation project(':lib-j-rci')
}
```

becomes this

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':lib-android-common-ui')
    implementation project(':android-lite')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation project(':lib-j-rci')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

and then sync Gradle, then add a test class with imports

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    @Test
    public  void useAppContext() throws Exception {
        // Context of the app under test.
        Context appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
        assertEquals("foo", appContext.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

if that does not work do `file > sync with file system` and `file > invalidate and restart`

Answer (score 2):

Add a new Android test. Select `Tests` view.

[image]

You will see all, one or no test packages.

[image]

Add one:

[image]

[image]

Go to your class and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Select `Create New Test...`, select "JUnit4", press "OK". You will see all available test packages, that you created before.

[image]

Make sure you have needed dependencies in build.gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
```